# Iteration issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, checkbox

I've got this issue with iterating via arrays. I've got an x number of buttons with the same x number of forms on one html page. associated with each of the forms is a random number of checkboxes on a form.The button, selectControl, selects/deselects all checkboxes for each form. Names for buttons and forms are created by using of an element and incrementing its number. This way I want to be able to loop through these elements preserving their unique ids.
I get an error "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" but didn't find anything to do with syntax, so I guess this has to be about iteration through arrays.

Below is my code:

```
var run_times = 2;     //declare how many buttons 
//function to look for checkboxes in each form
//receive the array of selectControl buttons from window.onload = function() 
function Check(frm){
  //get all checkboxes in an array
  var checkBoxes = frm.elements['chbx'];
  //run this for every form as specified in run_times var
  for (r = 0; r < run_times; r++) {
    //and for each checkbox found
    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
      checkBoxes[i].checked = (selectControl[r].innerHTML == "Select All") ? 'checked' : '';
    }
    //set the inner html for each button
    selectControl[r].innerHTML = (selectControl[r].innerHTML == "Select All") ? "Unselect All" : 'Select All';
  };
};

window.onload = function() 
{
  //loop
  for (r = 0; r < run_times; r++) 
  {
    //get a variable for each button
    var selectControl[r] = document.getElementById("selectControl"+[r]);
    //pass each of these variables to function above when button clicked
    selectControl[r].onClick= function(){ Check(document.myform[r])};
  };
};

/*window.onload = function(){

  var selectControl = document.getElementById("selectControl");
  selectControl.onclick = function(){Check(document.myform)};
};
```

and this is my html

```
<form name="myform1" method="" action="">
          <ul class="list-group" style="list-style:none">
            <li class="reco_item"><input name="chbx" class="reco_inp_box"type="checkbox"><p>one</p></li>
            <li class="reco_item"><input name="chbx" class="reco_inp_box"type="checkbox"><p>one</p></li>
            <li class="reco_item"><input name="chbx" class="reco_inp_box"type="checkbox"><p>one</p></li>
            <li class="reco_item"><input name="chbx" class="reco_inp_box"type="checkbox"><p>one</p></li>
            <li class="reco_item"><input name="chbx" class="reco_inp_box"type="checkbox"><p>one</p></li>
            <li class="reco_item"><input name="chbx" class="reco_inp_box"type="checkbox"><p>one</p></li>
            <li class="reco_item"><input name="chbx" class="reco_inp_box"type="checkbox"><p>one</p></li>
            <li class="reco_item"><input name="chbx" class="reco_inp_box"type="checkbox"><p>one</p></li>
          </ul>
        </form>

 <button id="selectControl1" name="sr_btn" class="btn btn-info reco_btn pull-right">Select all</button>              
      </div>
```

Comment: Which line did you get the error?

Comment: problem here `"selectControl"+[r]`?

Comment: I ran this through esvalidate and it was line 24 that was buggy, to which I've given the solution below.

Comment: definitely yes, but this is not the issue here..

Comment: If that's your complete code, you probably need to close the comment surrounding your `window.onload = ` block (missing `*/` at the end).

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectControl[r] = document.getElementById("selectControl"+[r]);
```

You meant:

```
selectControl[r] = document.getElementById("selectControl" + r);
```

Also you should declare:

```
var selectControl = [ ];
```

near the top of your code (before any function declarations).

Finally you should put a closing comment mark at the end of your code.

Comment: In addition, I think this too `document.myform[r]`?

Comment: Okay you're right, you should make the changes as I've revised in my answer. Specifically remove the `var` from `selectControl[r]` because you shouldn't be declaring a new variable when trying to fill in just an element of an array.